# Rotate multiple elements in Revit with C#

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I'm writing a Macro in Revit with C# for rotate multiple selected elements at a time. But I'm getting this error every time I try to run it:
"System.NullReferenceException: Object Reference Not Set to an instance of an object".
I don't know why I get this error since there are no "null" references in my selection. Does anybody know what is happening?
This is the code snippet:

```
        //Get document
        UIDocument uidoc = this.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;

        //Elements selection
        double angle = 45.0;
        var elements = uidoc.Selection.PickObjects(ObjectType.Element,"Select Elements") as List<Element>;
        foreach (Element element in elements)
        {
            LocationPoint lp = element.Location as LocationPoint;
            XYZ ppt = new XYZ(lp.Point.X,lp.Point.Y,0);
            Line axis = Line.CreateBound(ppt, new XYZ(ppt.X,ppt.Y,ppt.Z+10.0));

            using(Transaction rotate = new Transaction(doc,"rotate elements"))
            {
                rotate.Start();
                ElementTransformUtils.RotateElement(doc,element.Id,axis,angle);
                rotate.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: on what line is the error being thrown?

Comment: Also, I believe you're missing a line after your `Line axis = Line.CreateBound(ppt, new XYZ(ppt.X,ppt.Y,ppt.Z+10.0));` line. you need to tell the document to draw a line element. you've only told it you want a line, not to actually draw it. something like this `DetailLine myline = doc.Create.NewDetailCurve(myview, axis) as DetailLine;` you can more in the docs [here] (https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/9a8bd0d3-00dc-7a1c-39dd-e891899764ce.htm)

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work because the RotateElement Method asks for a Line, not a Detail Line :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a`NullReferenceException` because the return type of `PickObjects` is `IList<Reference>` and not `List<Element>`.

Try something like this:

```
var elements = uidoc.Selection.PickObjects(ObjectType.Element, "Select Elements")
.Select(o => uidoc.Document.GetElement(o));
```

Consider also that the angle is measured in radians and not in degrees as you wrote, or at least i think you don't want to rotate the element 45 rad ;).

Finally, do not forget that `element.Location` is not always a `LocationPoint`, depending on the selected element you could get a `LocationPoint`, `LocationCurve` or the base class ´Location´.

Comment: Thank you! It was, effectively, as you said, because it was asking for Elements, not Reference.